# SQLite: Splitting multiple selects into different columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to achieve the following looking output in SQL:

```
chair | Secretary | Year
------------------------
Matt  |   Susan   | 2006
Susan |   Joe     | 2005
```

From a database with tables `Members` and `Leaders`. Table `Members` looks as follows:

```
Name  | num
-------------
Matt  |  123
Susan |  456
Joe   |  789
```

Table `Leaders` looks as follows:

```
Year | Chair | Secretary
-------------------
2006 | 123   |  456
2005 | 456   |  789
```

So far I've come up with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT m.name FROM Members M, Leaders L
     WHERE M.num = L.secretary
          UNION ALL 
    SELECT m.name FROM MEMBER M, Leaders L WHERE M.num = L.chair
          UNION ALL
    SELECT L.year from Leaders L);
```

However, this selects all of the wanted parameters as one column. My question is: How do I make it so that the names in particular are split into `Chair` and `Secretary` columns when they are derived from the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you could build your query in this way:

```
SELECT l.year, m1.Name, m2.Name
FROM leaders l
INNER JOIN members m1 ON l.chair = m1.num
INNER JOIN members m2 ON l.secretary = m2.num
```

You can find a test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/75f1b6/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ALIAS`, which can be defined with `AS` keyword (that can be omitted). `ALIAS` can be used for tables and for columns, like in the example below:

```
SELECT
    ChairMembers.Name AS Chair,
    SecretaryMembers.Name AS Secretary,
    Year
FROM
    Leaders
INNER JOIN
    Members AS ChairMembers
ON
    Leaders.Chair = ChairMembers.num
INNER JOIN
    Members AS SecretaryMembers
ON
    Leaders.Secretary = SecretaryMembers.num
```

For more information you can read [this documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_alias_syntax.htm).